# Why geolocator's accuracy is low with windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, gps

I don't know why my app's GPS accuracy is lower than BingMap.
I use GeoLocator and set the accuracyinmeters to 1.
And I also try to set the accuracy to high. 
But the result is about 500 meters from where I actually am.
I also try the BingMap's app, and Its positioning result is quite accurate which confirms my gps is working.
Thx!

```
        Geolocator geolocator = new Geolocator();
        geolocator.DesiredAccuracyInMeters = 1;
        Accuracy.Text = geolocator.DesiredAccuracyInMeters.GetValueOrDefault().ToString();

        Geoposition position = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
        var gpsCoorCenter = new GeoCoordinate(position.Coordinate.Latitude, position.Coordinate.Longitude);
        WindMap.SetView(gpsCoorCenter, 15D);

        Pushpin pushpin = (Pushpin)this.FindName("MyPushpin");
        pushpin.GeoCoordinate = gpsCoorCenter;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the location was delivered by GPS, and not by network locationing.
I you don't  kno whow to check that, check if there is a speed or courde value asigned.
Then it is from GPS.

500m is not typical for GPS.
So look at the time stamp, is that an old location (from previous day), or a current one.
Next check also with  Google Earth.

Comment: Hi, I have added the code. I don't know how to check whether it was delivered by GPS. I didn't find any things about speed or course from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206956(v=vs.105).aspx